# How to update column with a string which contains &amp; and &reg;

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to update a string which contains & and ®.

Please help me - how to update a column, it's taking as substitution character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is about the tool you use.

In SQL*Plus, you'd have to *instruct* it to skip substitution variable prompt by using `set define off`:

```
SQL> create table test (col varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> set define off
SQL> insert into test (col) values ('P&amp;G');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test;

COL
----------
P&amp;G

SQL>
```

In other tools, there's a similar option, but it depends on what you actually use.

---

Without it, you'd get - as you already know:

```
SQL> set define on
SQL> insert into test (col) values ('P&reg;G');
Enter value for reg:
```

Comment: Actually i have to update html script which contains these two &amp; and &reg; .Now while updating the script its asking me the value , as its treating it as substitution operator.

Comment: A *script*? Stored in a file on your hard disk drive? If so, why do you use Oracle for such a purpose? If not, could you, please, edit the question and post some sample data which illustrates the problem?

Comment: its clob datatype column , where html script saved .

Comment: @vim as Littlefoot said, it depends on the tool you are using. SQL\*Plus, Toad, PL/SQL Developer, SQL Developer all implement substitution variables in different ways, because this is a client feature and not part of the SQL language. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 0):

replace & with chr(38)
and ® with chr(49838)

select 'Me ' || chr(38) || ' you ' || chr(49838) from dual;
results in:

Me & you ®

Comment: update Message_Type_Params 
set Message_Center_template = q'[ <html>
<head>
<style></style>
</head>
<body>
     <div>
      <div align="center" style="font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;">
            <b> card<sup><font size='3'>&reg;</font></sup>  Notification</b>
            <br />
        </div></div>'

Comment: i just posted my code in comment where i i am using &nbsp in a q operator,so when i run query its prompting for value.

Comment: If I understand you right you need to change to: select 'update Message_Type_Params set Message_Center_template = q''[ <html> <head> <style></style> </head> <body> <div> <div align="center" style="font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;"> <b> card<sup><font size=''3''>'||chr(38)||'reg;</font></sup> Notification</b> <br /> </div></div>''' from dual;